# best_in_place not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, I'm using the best in place gem to allow users to edit their photos caption in place. However, the text that is entered isn't being saved or stored in the database.

Here is a snapshot of the schema relevant to this area:

```
  create_table "photos", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "file"
    t.integer  "attachable_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "attachable_type"
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.boolean  "profile_photo",   default: false
  end
```

and here's the view code:

```
 <p class="summary-info"><%= text_field photo, :description, placeholder: 'Add a description...' %></p>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

```
 <p class="summary-info"><%= best_in_place photo, :description, type: :textarea, nil: 'Enter a Caption' %></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your aren't using the `best_in_place` helper method into the view. Check out the [README](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place#usage-of-rails-3-gem) or the [Railscasts #302](http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing).

You must do something like that:

```
<%= best_in_place @photo, :description, type: :input %>
```

Adjust it to your needs.

FYI: `text_field` is a [helper method provided by Rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-text_field).

Comment: I looked into it and I thought that the text_field was the helper method from the best_in_place gem for text fields? Do I add the best_in_place helper method a long with the text_field helper method? Thanks!