# Best_in_place gem not saving text area content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, best-in-place

So, I'm not sure why but when I enter some text in the text box and then refresh the page the text isn't saving. I'm using the correct DB field (description), so I'm not sure what's going wrong.

**_photo.html.erb**

```
<%= best_in_place photo, :description, type: :textarea, nil: 'Enter a Caption' %>
```

**photos schema**

```
create_table "photos", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "file"
    t.integer  "attachable_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "attachable_type"
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.boolean  "profile_photo",   default: false
  end

  add_index "photos", ["attachable_id"], name: "index_photos_on_attachable_id", using: :btree
  add_index "photos", ["attachable_type"], name: "index_photos_on_attachable_type", using: :btree
```

Why isn't it saving?

Cheers!

**Update:**

**show.js**

```
$('.modal-title').html('<%= @photo.title %>');
$('.modal-body').html('<%= j(render "modal_photo", photo: @photo) %>');
$('#myModal').modal();
```

**photos_controller (snip):**

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def show
    @photo = current_user.photos.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Comment: Please, add the content of your controller and the view from where you are calling the `_photo.html.erb` partial.

Comment: Sure - I've updated the post with the show and photos controller relevant code. Thanks!

Comment: Please, add the `update` action of your controller too.

Comment: You are using Rails3 or Rails4?

Comment: Rails 4. Let me remove that, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to save object instead single value attribute. replace it by

```
<%= best_in_place @photo, :description, type: :input %>
```

See this answer helps : [best_in_place not saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417383/best-in-place-not-saving)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem could be in the controller:

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json # Whatever formats you want to respond

  # Other actions...

  def update
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @photo.update_attributes(params[:photo])
        format.html { # Whatever you want to do... }
        format.json { respond_with_bip(@photo) }
      else
        format.html { # Whatever you want to do... }
        format.json { respond_with_bip(@photo) }
      end
    end
  end
```

Best in place provides a utility method you should use in your controller in order to provide the response that is expected by the javascript side, using the `:json` format. [More info in the gem's README](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place#controller-response-with-respond_with_bip).